# C# How can I check to see if a checkbox is checked on another form?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm using C# and I'd like to check to see if a checkbox on the main form is checked and if so run some code, the problem is I'm in a class file (file with no form, is class file correct?). What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best option is to create a `boolean` property on the Form that exposes the `Checked` value of the `CheckBox`.

```
public bool OptionSelected
{
    get { return checkBox.Checked; }
    set { checkBox.Checked = value; } // the set is optional
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for that, would I place this code on the event when the check box is checked? Thanks

Comment: Sorry about this but how do I use the code from my class?
Thanks

Comment: You would place this code in the form code. In order to use it from another instance, you would have to have a reference to the form that exposes this property.

Comment: Thanks Adam, sorry to push for clarity but I've not had to do this before so how would I create a reference to the form? Many thanks, I am trying to read around the subject at the moment but any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Every instance of a class has a reference. The reference is stored in the variable that you use to access that instance. For example, if I had a class called MyClass, doing MyClass x = new MyClass() creates a new instance and places a reference to it in the variable called 'x'. Inside of an instance, like in your form code (Forms are classes, by the way), the 'this' keyword means a reference to the current instance. I can't get any more specific other than to say that you would pass around the reference, usually by supplying 'this' as an argument somewhere, in order to refer to the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the form, and the form has to expose the checkbox (or a property which consults the checkbox).

There's no difference between UI programming and non-UI programming in this respect. How would ask for the `Name` property of a `Person` instance from a different class? You'd get a reference to the instance, and ask for the relevant property.

So you definitely need a reference to the form, and then it's one of:

```
bool checked = form.IsAdultCheckbox.Checked;
bool checked = form.IsAdult;
```

(Where the `IsAdult` property would return `someCheckbox.Checked`.)

The actual property names may be wrong here (e.g. `Checked` may not return a `bool`) but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Jamie - Be careful of threads here!  If the class is operating in a background thread, don't forget to Invoke back to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Can you define an interface with a property, have the form implement the interface and return true if the checkbox is checked, and pass an instance of this interface to your class?

For example:

```
interface IMyFormFlag
{
    bool IsChecked { get; }
}

public class MyForm : Form, IMyFormFlag
{
    CheckBox chkMyFlag;

    bool IsChecked { get { return chkMyFlag.Checked; } }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public void DoSomethingImportant(IMyFormFlag formFlag)
    {
        if (formFlag.IsChecked)
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like using set or get. I did it like this:

```
if (checkBox.IsChecked.Equals(true))
{
//insert code here
}
```

Comment: This isn't a proper C# way of comparing the value.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with placing this in the CheckChanged event?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this   it works fine for me

```
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(CheckBox1.IsChecked))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("true");
      }
    else
       {
         MessageBox.Show("false"); 
       }
```