# If one checkbox is checked, set the other to unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have two checkboxes on my form; `chkBuried` and `chkAboveGround`. **I want to set it up so if one is checked, the other is unchecked. How can I do this?**

I have tried the `CheckChanged` property:

```
private void chkBuried_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkAboveGround.Checked = false;
}
private void chkAboveGround_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkBuried.Checked = false;
}
```

And it works, just not as well as I hoped. That is, when I check `chkBuried`, then check `chkAboveGround`, both boxes become unchecked before I can check another one again.

Comment: Use radio buttons if they are exclusive

Comment: @DeveloperGuo In this situation I want to use checkboxes. If there isn't a way to do this with checkboxes I will go back to radio buttons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

modify your code as below.

```
private void chkBuried_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkAboveGround.Checked = !chkBuried.Checked;
}
private void chkAboveGround_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkBuried.Checked = !chkAboveGround.Checked;
}
```

Comment: A new situation has evolved: What if I want to uncheck both boxes? Currently if I check one, then uncheck it, the other is checked again.

Comment: For the new scenario, you can modify the first handler's body like ... chkAboveGround.Checked = (chkBuried.Checked)? false: chkAboveGround.Checked;  and similarly changes for the second handler

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use check_click instead of check_changed

```
        private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
            checkBox3.Checked = false;
        }

        private void checkBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            checkBox3.Checked = false;
        }

        private void checkBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the behavior you have explained is that you are using `CheckedChanged` event, which means that when you are setting the Checked property of a `CheckBox` manually, the event is also fired, causing another box to react again.

Therefore, the following might help you:

```
private void chkBuried_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBuried.Checked == true) {
        chkAboveGround.Checked = false;
    } else {
        chkAboveGround.Checked = true;
    }
}

private void chkAboveGround_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkAboveGround.Checked == true) {
        chkBuried.Checked = false;
    } else {
        chkBuried.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 29.03.2020**: functionally the code in my answer is the same as the answer given by Riz. Nevertheless, I am leaving the code as I put it originally since it might make the whole situation easier to understand for the people who are new to coding. If you are to implement anything similar in production code, *please use the answer by Riz as an example*.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work unfortunately, however your explanation helped me understand why mine wasn't working :) Thanks Danek

Comment: @Ben, sorry I did not get the question completely correctly. Riz's explanation is really good :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer radio buttons, but you can do something like this:

```
public void CheckACheckBox(Checkbox ck)
{
    foreach (Control ckb in this.Controls)
    {
       if ((ckb is CheckBox) && (ckb == ck))
          ck.Checked = true;
       else
          ck.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<CheckBox> groupOfCheckBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
void InitFunction() {
    groupOfCheckBoxes.Add(checkbox1);
    groupOfCheckBoxes.Add(checkbox2);
    groupOfCheckBoxes.Add(checkbox3);
    foreach (CheckBox cb in groupOfCheckBoxes)
     cb.Click += checkbox_Click
}
void checkbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 foreach (CheckBox cb in groupOfCheckBoxes) {
  cb.IsChecked = cb == sender;
 }
}
```

However I would suggest radio boxes as well.
The code above is untested and may have some typos

Comment: It depends on the usage. If the checkboxes are not contained within the same parent you need some way of keeping track of them. 

If the group has large listing of checkboxes, you will only have to add to the group in one area.

If you only have two checkboxes, then this is more then overkill.

You did specify two checkboxes, I apologize.

Comment: I can see the potential for it, I'm in no way saying this is incorrect, but for this case specifically, I only have two checkboxes on the same form. So for my case it's  bit much :)

Comment: I would go with DeveloperGuo with the Radioboxes, then can be styled however you want them ( just like checkboxes). Also you not have extra code to handle the checking / unchecking.

Comment: When I was looking for a solution to my problem, I came acorss this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410923/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-to-see-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-on-another-form possibly a better use for this code?

Answer (score 0):

Better version, allows the user to uncheck boxes.

```html
        private void chkOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkTwo.Checked == true)
            {
                chkTwo.Checked = !chkOne.Checked;
            }
        }

        private void chkTwo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkOne.Checked == true)
            {
                chkOne.Checked = !chkTwo.Checked;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option and easiest way for me was to create a Click event instead of a CheckedChanged event.
This method works perfectly with two or more checkbox and allows to have them all unchecked.

```
    private void chkOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkTwo.Checked = false;
    }

    private void chkTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkOne.Checked = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for two unchecked boxes, since they are already unchecked it is simpler.
I had to do this myself also.

```
private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    business.IsChecked = false;
}

private void business_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customer.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to show or not show a table when activating the CheckBox, how they were two, if I activated both, everything was fine, but if I tried to deactivate one later, the other was also deactivated. PD: The default value for the tables that I used was Visible=false. The solution I got was the following:

```
 protected void YourNameOfMethodForBothCheckBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox_1.Checked == true)
        {
            Table_1.Visible = true;

            if (CheckBox_2.Checked == true)
            {
                Table_2.Visible = true;
            }
            else { Table_2.Visible = false; }


        }
        else
        {
            Table_1.Visible = false;

            if (CheckBox_2.Checked == false)
            {
                Table_2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Table_2.Visible = true;

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v Primitive method usually use it by defination 2 integer guide to prevent infinity loop when change checke box state:

```
int guide1=0; //one time to checkbox1 event
int guide2=0; //one time to checkbox2 event
private void chkBuried_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(guide1==0)
 { 
  chkAboveGround.Checked = false;
  chkBuried.Checked = true;
    guide1=1;
    guide2=0;
  }

}
private void chkAboveGround_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(guide2==0)
 { 
  chkBuried.Checked = false;
  chkAboveGround.Checked = true;  
    
    guide2=1;
    guide1=0;
  }   
}
```