# checkbox checked change will disabled the other checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, webforms, isenabled

I have two checkboxes. If the first checkbox checked, the second checbox will be disabled and if the first checkbox unchecked, the second checkbox will be enabled.

```
<div class="data">
<asp:CheckBox ID="firstCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="LabelText" EnableViewState="False" AutoPostBack="True" />
</div>

<div class="data">
<asp:CheckBox ID="secondCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="LabelText" EnableViewState="False" AutoPostBack="True" />
</div>
```

Here is my control part at the Page_Load;

```
if (firstCheckBox.Checked)
{
    secondCheckBox.Enabled = false;

}
else
{
    secondCheckBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

When I checked the firstcheckbox, nothing happens to the secondcheckbox. After I checked the second checkbox, secondcheckbox has been checked and disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: is this webforms?

Comment: yes it is @JohnB

Comment: did you tried to use FirstCheckBox `CheckedChanged` event ? just put `secondCheckBox.Enabled= ! firstCheckBox.Checked;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javascript` to enable or disable checkbox.
Here `firstCheckBox` & `secondCheckBox` are the id's of your checkbox.

```
if(document.getElementById("firstCheckBox").checked = true)
document.getElementById("secondCheckBox").disabled = true;
else
document.getElementById("secondCheckBox").disabled = false;
```

Comment: For standard setup you should use `document.getElementById("<%= firstCheckBox.ClientID %>")`. Server controls may rendered with different `id` value unless `ClientIDMode="Static"` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with checkBox CheckChanged event.
Please remove condition from load event of your form and add below code.

```
<div class="data">
<asp:CheckBox ID="firstCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="LabelText" EnableViewState="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_Check_Clicked" />
</div>

<div class="data">
<asp:CheckBox ID="secondCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="LabelText" EnableViewState="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_Check_Clicked" />
</div>

protected void CheckBox1_Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
if(CheckBox1.Checked==true)
{
CheckBox2.Enable=false;
}
else
{
CheckBox2.Enable=true;
}
}


protected void CheckBox2_Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
if(CheckBox2.Checked==true)
{
CheckBox1.Enable=false;
}
else
{
CheckBox1.Enable=true;
}
}
```

So you should have two CheckChanged events on each checkbox individual. Autopostback true. Same you can do with only one event if you apply some logic.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to set `Enabled` state of second checkbox in server-side, hence you should handle [`CheckedChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event from first checkbox like this example:

```
private void firstCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondCheckBox.Enabled = !firstCheckBox.Checked;
}
```

The problem why the checkbox `checked` event handler is not triggered is because you're putting the logic inside `Page_Load` event instead of `CheckedChanged` event from first checkbox.

Similar issue:

[If one checkbox is checked, set the other to unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367720/if-one-checkbox-is-checked-set-the-other-to-unchecked)