# Only allow one checkbox to be selected

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two checkboxes and I want them to start of unchecked.  but if select one, and then choose to change your mind and select the other box, then the previous one goes unchecked.  My code so far is below, I am so close.  But when I run my app when you select one they both turn on or off.  Please help.

```
    private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (business.IsChecked == true)
        {
            business.IsChecked = !customer.IsChecked;
        }

        if (business.IsChecked == false)
        {
            business.IsChecked = !customer.IsChecked;
        }

    }

    private void business_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customer.IsChecked == true)
        {
           customer.IsChecked = !business.IsChecked;
        }

        if (customer.IsChecked == false)
        {
            customer.IsChecked = !business.IsChecked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons? Probably better from a UX perspective, and definitely easier to implement.

Comment: Xamarin Froms don't have radio buttons and Im using Telerik Controls.  they only have checkboxes

Comment: I also tried something like this but I got an error

Comment: chkAboveGround.Checked = (chkBuried.Checked)? false: chkAboveGround.Checked;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If one checkbox is checked, set the other to unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367720/if-one-checkbox-is-checked-set-the-other-to-unchecked)

Comment: Why do you have two different `if` statements which both contain the same code in the method body? Since you do the same thing if `customer.IsChecked` is `true` or `false`, why not just remove all that extra code and have `customer.IsChecked = !business.IsChecked;`

Comment: @RittenRA How is that any different than `chkAboveGround.Checked = !chkBuried.Checked;`?

Comment: Aside from the redundant code, what you have works fine in winforms. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

You need to think through your code logic a bit more. For instance:

```
private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (business.IsChecked == true)
    {
        business.IsChecked = !customer.IsChecked;
    }

    if (business.IsChecked == false)
    {
        business.IsChecked = !customer.IsChecked;
    }

}
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    business.IsChecked = !customer.IsChecked;
}
```

You always change the value of `business.IsChecked` to `!customer.IsChecked` regardless of the value of `business.IsChecked`.

Also bear in mind that your behaviour is slightly different than what you described. Even if you correct your logic to the above. If you check customer, then business should remain unchecked, however if you then untick customer you would check business. What you described was just that you wanted to uncheck customer if you checked business. Maybe the behavior is correct, but it's not what you described.

If what I've described is not what you want, then you should only implement this logic when the control changing is changed to true:

```
private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(customer.IsChecked)
        business.IsChecked = false;
}
```

As for why you're getting this behavior. I suspect this is your problem: [If one checkbox is checked, set the other to unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367720/if-one-checkbox-is-checked-set-the-other-to-unchecked) and maybe changing to `check_clicked` instead of `check_changed` so you don't trigger your own result handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XLabs plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/2.0.5782 if you know how to use NuGet package manager. It has radio buttons.

Comment: xlabs.form is no longer maintained and has bugs also.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simplifying the code a bit.  Should work out the kinks.

```
private void customer_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (customer.IsChecked)
    {
        business.IsChecked = false;
    }
}

private void business_IsCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (business.IsChecked)
    {
        customer.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then when you uncheck one box, the other one remains unchecked. I don't think that's what they're after..?